# Sql Server Reporting Service (SSRS) 2005 Operation timeout issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, iis-6

I know similar questions have been asked before...
I am using SQL server 2005, with SSRS 2005 installed on the same box. (aka. production DB, Report DB/TempDB, Database engine, and SSRS all in the same box).
We have about 200 reports deployed in the box.
SSRS/DB is running on a W2k3 64-bit VM.

Now the problem...

Occasionally almost on a daily basis our users get the 'operation timeout' error (error in XML document....).  At first I thought it was a report size problem, but then when I try the Report Manager URL (http://<>/reports), nothing appears on the browser.  The only thing I can do is to recycle the Report server IIS pool and it will work again.  Everytime when the 'operation timeout' happens, the Report Manager URL will not work, and I can't find any logs in IIS to indicate there's a problem.

I researched on the net and found that some people have put a dummy report as part of the SQL server agent job which runs every 10 minutes from 9-5 to 'warm up' the SSRS.  The dummy report made a small connection to the DB on one row from a very small table.  The operation timeout problem seems to have disappeared for 95% of time, but it still happens.  Strange enough, when the operation timeout problem happens, I notice the dummy report job has also stopped working.  In this case, I had to recycle the IIS pool, and start the SQL server job again, and then SSRS will work again (until the same problem happens next time)

The error I got from the SQL server job is:
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

However I am totally confused by how the IIS issue on the report server somehow affects the SSRS job.  Maybe I am on the wrong track but that's bizzare.

My observation so far is if it takes forever for the Report Manager URL (http://<>/reports) to appear it is a bad sign that something has gone terribly wrong on SSRS.

I have also added a new task which call the SSRS Report Manager http://<>/reports URL using PowerShell in order to 'warm-up' the IIS but it does not seem to make much difference.

Can someone point me to the right direction?  Thanks.  WM

Answer (score 0):

In the past, after much research, I've found memory allocation for SSRS to be the root of many issues.  You can try this.

Add the following into the `<Service>` node in the rsreportserver.config file

```
<WorkingSetMaximum>4000000</WorkingSetMaximum>
```

The file is typically in c:\program files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.iMIS\Reporting Services\ReportServer

This sets the maximum memory available for the report which also set the minimum memory to 60% of the maximum.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159206(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Will find the value and give it a go.

Comment: Before I made the changes in the config file, I just want to share some observations here:The 'operation time out' error happened again this morning for a report snapshot.  I went to the server and type http://localhost/reports and, as expected, IIS stopped and I had to recycle the appPool to make it working.  Then I looked at the history of the report and found that the snapshot has been created (100MB) and I could run the report with no issue within the server, however it took  A LONG TIME for it to convert to PDF.  I am more incline to think the timeout problem is caused by PDF conversion.

Comment: In addition to my observation.  Typing http://<dbserver>/reports in the morning defintely caused the IIS and my SSRS warm-up job to stop in the morning. SO even my powershell task that supposed to warm up the IIS does not help either